# Google Maps - displays blank when browser language changed

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I display a google map on a web page, based on latitude and longitude.  All works fine.  But if I change my browser language to any language (e.g. French, German) from the default English, then the map goes blank (google map box displayed, but no map).

I tried adding language=en to the script link; makes no difference.  Anyone who can shed some light?

Code is shown below:-

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("50.00123", "0.012311");
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapdiv'), mapOptions);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Event Location'
      });
    }    

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Your Latitude and Longitude should be numbers, not strings (probably not the problem).

Comment: The problem exists at least in IE and Chrome, on both Windows and Mac.

Comment: Lat and Long are numbers, of course

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this yet?

Comment: no, I did post this as a bug on google's site.